# Which phones ship with manufacturer-provided root?

Tags: root-access

I'd like to buy a phone that either ships with factory-installed `su`, or where the manufacturer provides official instructions/downloads for installing one. Do such phones exist?

Answer (score 3):

If you buy a nexus phone, You get official instructions from Google on how to root the phone. I'd recommend you hold on a couple of months for the phone that will replace the nexus 4. I have had a nexus 4 for half a year and it's pretty good for the money I paid for it.

Answer (score 0):

**NO**. Most phones come with "stock" ROMS, possibly stock Android or stock manufacturer-modified ROMs. Most manufacturers, if not all, will not give you root access because they don't want you to play around with your phone, which may give them headaches (a metaphor) in case you go to them to fix it. Some may not even fix phones that are rooted.